# List comments with updatedMin param returns all comments?

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried this page to learn the comments list method.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list#try-it

I wanted to see the effect of updatedMin query param. I gave 2014-01-04T17:50:44.012Z as the value for updatedMin param

It seems it formed the following url properly.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B4Qf3Z8Q9xwOSUNaMkx0T25TNms/comments?updatedMin=2014-01-04T17%3A50%3A44.012Z&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

However the list included ALL the comments.... whereas I was expecting zero (as the year given is 2014)

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried this out too and appears to be ignoring the date. Query looks OK and if the date format was wrong it should have produced a 40x error. Filed a bug & will update when I know more.

Comment: May I ask when should this be expected to be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will like to know if the above issue has been fixed by now. That will help me in resuming my development. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveBazyl: this issue still exists as of today. Any update?